# Unable to use Import in jsx files in Play/scala app

Tags: scala, reactjs, playframework, jsx, babeljs

I am using play2.5/scala with React. I have it working mostly, however I am not able to use "Import" statements in JSX. I don't know if I am including all that is required.

```
...
"org.webjars" % "jquery" % "2.1.4",
"org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.6" exclude("org.webjars", "jquery"),
"org.webjars" % "requirejs" % "2.1.19",
"org.webjars" % "react" % "15.2.1",
"org.webjars" % "marked" % "0.3.2-1",
"org.webjars.npm" % "react-dom" % "15.3.0",
"org.webjars.npm" % "babel" % "6.3.26",
...
```

I get this error if I use import:

```
Elements.jsx:1: Parse Error: Line 1: Illegal import declaration
[error] import React from 'react'; 
[error] ^
[error] one error found
[error] (www/web-assets:reactjs) com.typesafe.sbt.web.CompileProblemsException
```

Also, I am not able use following JS snippet:

```
handleEditorChange = (e) => {
  console.log('Content was updated:', e.target.getContent());
}
```

I believe this is ES16 syntax. Any thing missing in my environment ?

Comment: Maybe a stupid comment, but, did you update your project with `activator update` after editing your build.sbt ?

Comment: Tried that - no change, thanks!